# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf dropdown box validation re-populate input text field on submit

Tags: forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dropdownbox

I have an index page that accepts a value (e.g. mobile number) and a selection via dropdown box.  I want to force the user to select something from a dropdown box and not just accept the first option as default.  To do this I have added a "Please Select ..." option to the dropdown box.  If the submit button is pressed the controlled .

Part of my controller looks similar to this:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ModelAndView validateSerialNum(@ModelAttribute("device") Device d,
                                    HttpServletRequest request
                                    ) {
        
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    if ("none_selected".equalsIgnoreCase(d.getSupportAction())) {
        log.trace("=== No \"I Would Like To...\" selection was made ===");
        System.out.println("DEVICE Object: " + d.toString());
        mav.addObject("device", d);
        mav.addObject("allSupportActions", getSupportActions());
        mav.addObject("RobotError", "You have not selected a valid action...");
        mav.setViewName("index");
    }

...
```

The Form on my index page looks similar to this:

```
<form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${device}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group" id="tmpBody">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="mobileNum">Mobile Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileNum" autofocus="autofocus" name="mobileNum" th.text="*{mobileNum}" th.field="*{mobileNum}"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="inputState">I would like to:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select class="form-control" name="supportAction">
                     <option th:value="none_selected" selected="true">Please Select ...</option>
                     <option th:value="actOne">Action One</option>
                     <option th:value="actTwo">Action Two</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        
...
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

What I am wanting to achieve is that if the submit button has been pressed but "Action One" or "Action Two" has NOT been selected I want to display the index page again with an error (this part is working great) but what I cannot get right is I want to populate the Mobile Number that was previously entered in the mobileNum field.

Comment: In the index page, for mobileNum, did you try once with just having the field attribute? Without the other attributes like id, value, name, text.

Comment: I did,  I have also tried without field and only using id, value and name.

I also tried to add a new field to ModelAndView (mav)

mav.addObject("mobileNum", d.getMobileNum());

and then reference that using both id, value and name as well as field.

I also changed mobileNum in the above test to mNum.

Could it have something to do with caching?

Comment: Not sure. By any chance, model gets changed after the if-loop?

Comment: I have tried to add "return mav;" inside that if loop to try avoid that situation you mentioned.  Same result.